# How to convert a batch of image frames to a video of the same quality

Tags: python, opencv

I used this script to convert an 18-second video to its frames. In total, I got 558 frames.

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from os.path import isfile, join

vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture('PXL_20211116_020738341.mp4')
success,image = vid_cap.read()
count = 0

while success:
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  success,image = vid_cap.read()
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1
```

The output (558 frames) is basically the same video with some masks. I want to turn those frames into a new video that is also 18 seconds. Meaning, I want the original video and the output video to run in the same motion quality. How can I achieve this with Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "same motion quality"? Do you mean same framerate (fps)? You may look for a way to get the fps of a given mp4 file, and look for a way to set the fps when creating a new video file.

Comment: just use ffmpeg. you aren't even doing anything in that snippet you posted. just copy the video file then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.
Read your jpeg file to an images array and use VideoWriter.
You are also able to set fps (maybe 558/18) to this function.

https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/

Comment: The fps is a problem. Its incredibly fast. Its an 18s output but the frames are repeating multiple times.